# multiple Ok in controller is not Ok

Tags: scala, playframework, response

I was expecting `t` or `f` as a response but its giving `hello`

```
def check1 = Action { implicit request =>
    val flag=List(true,false)
      if(Random.shuffle(flag).head){
        println("true")
        Ok("t")
      }else{
         println("false")
          Ok("f")
      }
    Ok("hello")
  }
```

why is it so?

I was Thinking that it will not execute the last Ok the 1st Ok gives the response and remaining code will not execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if/else` block always return the `Result` (ends the action and sends content to browser), use this instead:

```
def check1 = Action { implicit request =>
    val flag=List(true,false)
      if(Random.shuffle(flag).head){
        println("true")
        Ok("t")
      }else{
         println("false")
          Ok("hello")
      }
  }
```

or

```
def check1 = Action { implicit request =>
    val flag=List(true,false)
      if(Random.shuffle(flag).head){
        println("true")
        Ok("t")
      }

    Ok("hello")

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you're getting `"hello"`, this is the last statement of your block - I don't really understand the point of this `Ok("hello")` actually, everything would work just fine without it. Your `if/else` has either `"t"` or `"f"` for value, but you never use it.

This will work:

```
def check1 = Action { implicit request =>
  val flag=List(true,false)
  if(Random.shuffle(flag).head){
    println("true")
    Ok("t")
  }else{
    println("false")
    Ok("f")
  }
}
```